# Sudo nano error

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am trying to run this command `apt install sudo nano`
and getting this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libncursesw6 : Depends: libtinfo6 (= 6.4-2ubuntu0.1) but 6.4+20230625-2 is to be installed                           
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package
```

Comment: What release are you using? One of the versions is from Ubuntu repositories for *mantic*  (is that what you're using??) where as the other isn't, thus I'd work out what release you're using and if it's not *mantic* explore your package source for the other package as it does **not** match the current rule for *mantic* (which is `libtinfo6 (= 6.4+20230625-2)` and not what your message shows).  Your issue could also be *stale* software lists; but firstly work out what you're running (*and tell us so we can help you*), then `sudo apt update` & scan output, no warnings/missing lines etc, then..

Comment: This looks strange... With any Ubuntu both `sudo` and `nano`are normally installed from the very beginning (after setting up your Ubuntu), and then; normal `apt` use is: `$ sudo apt install nano`. So: what exactly are you trying to do?